# Is it possible to find a graphable function solution for the Brachistochrone problem without using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric, calculus-of-variations, trigonometric-integrals

The solutions of for the Brachistochrone problem make use of trigonometric substitution to generate parametric equations for x and y. Does a solution exist without trigonometric substitution?

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation of the cycloid profile (curvature radii ratio) when

$$ \tan \phi = y^{'}  $$

is

$$ \frac{y y ^{''}}{1+y^{'2}}= -\frac12 $$

Its integral

$$ \cos \phi =  \pm \sqrt{y/c}   $$

involves cos function which is trigonometric... so at  property level  itself embedded and trig is unavoidable.